# Animate Panel Width Depending on Number of Seconds Provided

Tags: vb.net, animation, width, panel, seconds

Is it possible to animate the panel width for three seconds or depending on the number of seconds I pass on the method/function?

I'm currently using timer to change the width but it doesn't have specific number of seconds to finish the animation.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick()
    If Panel1.Width < 50 Then
        Panel1.Width += 10
    Else
        Me.Dispose()
        Timer1.Enabled = Flase
    End If
End Sub
```

What i want is to have a function like this

```
Private Sub AnimateWidth(ByRef pnl As Panel, ByVal MaxWidth As Integer, ByVal NumberOfSeconds as Double)
    'This is where I'm Lost. I dont have any idea what to do
End Sub
```

Comment: This is basic mathematics, and I mean primary school stuff.  You have a number of pixels to move and a number of seconds over which to move.  Those are fixed.  The variables are the `Interval` of the `Timer`, which determines the number of `Tick` events per second, and the number of pixels to move on each `Tick`.  You don't need help with determining which combinations of those two variables will give you the desired result.

Comment: Do you mean: you have a period of time (3 seconds) and you need to expand your panel up to a specific measure in this lapse of time, or should it grow to an indefinite measure until the given interval elapses?

Comment: @Jimi Yes i want it to expand to a specific measure for 3 seconds.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if it's so basic then why can't you just show and teach me or anyone who will have this kind of problem, you know, those who are VERY NEW to programming how its done, rather than showing everyone else how inferior you think I am to you. Thanks BTW.

Comment: Because I'm not here to spoon-feed people who aren't prepared to think for themselves. I commented specifically to point out that this is not actually a programming problem, so the fact that you're new to programming is completely irrelevant.  As I said, it's a basic maths problem and I'll wager that you're not new to basic maths. Writing the code is not solving the problem. You should be solving the problem before writing any code. You haven't even tried to do that. It's simple multiplication and division. If you really need me to show you how to do that then you have greater issues.

Comment: If you are prepared to make an effort to actually work out what the code has to do first and then encounter an issue implementing it in code then that is the type of question this site is for and I'll be the first to provide an answer to such a question. If you want an explanation of simple arithmetic then this is not the place to get it.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney you're very helpful.

Comment: @jmcilhinney FYI, i already tried all i can think of, tried changing the timer's interval, tried changing the increment of panel's width, tried having two timer- one for the increment and one for checking how many seconds have passed, none of this have worked for me, now i ask this question and all you can give is that? Thank you very much, and BTW this function is done correctly (if someone [better than you] can help me) to address how long the messagebox to show, (made my own messagebox to have a modern look) and i put a small panel on the bottom that acts as a progress bar.

Comment: And therein lies the problem. You're trying to make this a programming problem when it's not.  It's a basic maths problem.  Put down your keyboard and mouse, pick up a pen and paper and DO THE MATH.  If you won't take that advice then it is you that stands in your way and nothing else.  You're expecting someone to tell you how to write code to do something when you don't actually know what that something is.  THAT is the problem.  You won't take the time work out what that something is and that's why you can't write code to do it.  If you knew what that something was, the code would be easy.

Comment: The fact is that I have provided help.  I've told you how to approach this problem in order to be able to work it out yourself.  The fact that that is not the help you want does mean that it's not help.  You can wait for someone to give you a fish or you can accept that you have already been taught how to fish in school maths class and put that knowledge that you already have to use.  You say that you have already tried everything you can think of.  Well, you clearly didn't think to treat it as a basic maths problem that you can work out for yourself with pen and paper.  You're welcome.

Comment: BTW @jmcilhinney if you're too cool to help with this kind of problem, why comment on the first place?

Comment: you're the best @jmcilhinney THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: You want to believe that I think that I'm too cool to help because that lets you believe that you have done nothing wrong and it's all my problem. The fact of the matter is that I make comments like those here because I want everyone to be the best developer they can and if someone refuses to apply basic principles they learned in maths class as a child then they are certainly not going to achieve that.  This is a VERY SIMPLE PROBLEM.  I have no doubt that you are quite capable of solving it yourself.  If you're really not then programming isn't for you.

Comment: If A is the number of pixels to move and B is the number of milliseconds over which to move then A/B gives you the number of pixels per millisecond to move. If your `Timer` raises a `Tick` every C milliseconds then how many pixels, D, do you have to move each `Tick`? PRIMARY! SCHOOL! MATHS! One division and one multiplication.  Act like a child?  Get treated like a child.  It's not stupidity that prevents people solving easy problems like this.  It's laziness.  That laziness is compounded when they refuse to do basic maths even when it's pointed out to them.

Comment: so that's your solution? then what do you think i did when i said i already changed the timers interval and changing the increment for the panel's width? Anyway, because of your coolness i tried looking into the timer control, it is only limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds, so i'll be going deeper into System.Timers namespace. If you just posted that first rather than making a fuss something about i'm not ready to think for myself, then everything would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub FadeIn(ByVal TotalSeconds As Single, ByRef frm As Form)
    If TotalSeconds = 0 Then
        frm.Opacity = 1
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim [then] As Double = DateAndTime.Timer
    Dim difference As Double = 0
    Do While difference < 1
        frm.Opacity = difference
        difference = (DateAndTime.Timer - [then]) / TotalSeconds
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    Loop
    frm.Opacity = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney i was talking about something like this dad.